# How to open Safari from ios app with specified cookies

Tags: ios, swift, safari

I want to open Safari from my iOS application with specified cookies. But i found that NSHTTPCookieStorage is not shared between apps in iOS. So i don't know how to do that. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go with `SFSafariViewController` which will launch the web page inside your app and whatever the cookies you have those will be retained by `SFSafariViewController` without extra work.